# I need to replace the value NULL with the string - format in the ms sql request

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question on MS SQL request.
I have a task.
In the table, in the line with the date, if there is NULL, I need to replace it with a word.

Сolumn format - date.

Example

```
2020-09-22 11:30:13.273 | 2020-09-25 12:15:15.273
2020-09-23 08:32:21.273 |    NULL
```

there should be a string-format instead of NULL

Comment: Use `coalecse()`. But what's the column data type?

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of the column?  If you are -- very improperly -- using strings for `datetime` values, then you can simply use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(col2, 'a word')
```

If `col2` is properly stored as a date/time value, then you need to convert it to a string:

```
select coalesce(convert(varchar(255), col2), 'a word')
```

All that said, I strongly encourage you to keep the `NULL` value.  If you need to change it to something else, you can do so at the application layer.

Comment: select 
gcn.Id as temp_Id,
pid.DateStart,
pid.DateEnd,

from GeneralNode gcn

inner join Stationary sc on gcn.Id = sc.Id
inner join PatientInDepartment pid on pid.Id_Card = sc.Id

Comment: in this query, in the DateEnd column, there are NULL values. I need to replace NULL with 'Stay'